# Application development with Rational ClearQuest

Tags: vbscript, clearquest

Has anyone had experience with developing web apps using ClearQuest?  Looking at the features, it mentions process automation but I'm not sure how large of a process/application it can support.  Our group gave up a small section of a larger application to another group that used ClearQuest to web-enabled the process but now the ClearQuest tools are being pushed on us to web-enable the entire application.  I have a ASP.NET background but ClearQuest is very wizard like and the only code that I've seen is called "BASIC" and it looks a lot like VBScript.

Comment: Sorry I have not used it for web apps specifically and there is some small amount of ambiguity in whether you are exposing CQ using web apps or developing web apps with it.

Comment: We will be developing a custom web app with it.

Comment: I have built a .Net based ASP application that replicates their software. It is doable... sometimes a bit dicey though but very doable.

Answer (score 1):

Clearcase/Clearquest has decent integration with Rational Applicaiton Developer.  I am not sure if you arsking about its strenghts or actually exposing ClearQuest to the web.  You can do the obligatory and lame activity of writing CGI/PERL scripts to expose some of the features to the web.  You can use perl or VBScript to write CC/CQ hooks.  It has its own perl build included in the product called ratperl.  It has fantastic command line support but it comes at a price of complexity.  CC/CQ is very powerful provided you think about the implementation in your organization very carefully.  It can support very powerful work flows and is highly customizable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several APIs which allow you to do what you want, write a WebApp.

CQWeb itself is built using the CM API, which allows a Java application (web or non-web) to be build. A tutorial is here:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.team_api_cq_tut.doc/topics/teamapi_cq_abstract.htm

You could implement a basic web application using perl-CGI, since CQ has a Perl API.

You can write an ASP/C# web application because ClearQuest has a OLE (Visual Basic) API. The original ClearQuest Web application was built using the Visual Basic API

So the answer is yes, it is possible.
Wouldn't it be nice it supported a JavaScript API? Then we could write nodeJS CQ applications.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible, for a VS style integration I would either wrap the cqole.dll or use the OSLC connectors to get access to the RESTful interface. While the cqole is the C++ API and it is not officially supported this will suite you better than trying to implement this with the VBScript API. If you are more comfortable with just using the web services I would check out jazz.net where the wiki explains the bridge in gory details.

Answer (score 0):

You dont exactly develop webapp with ClearQuest, CQ is only a process automation tool that build on logic and state transitions, and the interactions are scripted in either VBScript or Perl.

However do note that it has always been a pain to manage CQ codes as the "Designer" itself is a completely broken tool. It supports version tracking but doesnt tell u the difference between versions. The built-in code editor doesnt have syntax highligting, and it doesnt support parallel development. I can go on and on.

In the later versions, (version 7 onwards I supposed), CQ comes with eclipse based client AND designer tools, which supposedly enhance the whole experience. But I dont have too much experience with it to comment.

As for the web component, it runs on the websphere layer and simply is a application/presentation layer for users to access CQ through a HTTP protocol. It has 90% of the features of a full CQ client, and is usually easier to maintain and deploy to a wide user group.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://open-services.net/ for information on development using Open Services for Lifecycle Collaboration.